Adding reference voltage to oscillator
I have designed a very basic Schmitt Trigger LFO. However, the power supply for the op amp has to be 9 and 0 V instead of 9 and -9V. For doing so, i supose that i need to add some voltage reference voltage but i can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my working schematic with no voltage reference.

Thanks!

When the comparator (op-amp) is powered from 0V and +9V, the output will be either 0V or +9V, meaning that the capacitor voltage (at the comparator's inverting input, node A below) will also swing up and down between those extremes. Therefore you require switching thresholds (at the non-inverting input, node B below) lying somewhere between those extremes, too.
When using dual supplies of ±9V, those thresholds would be symmetrical about the half way point at 0V, but with supplies of 0V and 9V, that "half way" point becomes +4.5V. Suitable thresholds might be \$+4.5V \pm 2V\$, or \$+6.5V\$ and \$+2.5V\$, or almost any pair of voltages symmetric above and below half of the supply.
In fact, any pair of voltages would do as long as they are different, and they both lie well within the 0V to 9V range, but here I'll aim for symmetry about +4.5V.
The easiest way I can think of to do this uses a resistor potential divider (R3 and R4 below) to obtain +4.5V at B, and then to modulate that up and down slightly using feedback via resistor R5:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Make a Vcc/2 node using buffer and connect C1 and R4 Gnds to it.
Now your schmitt can be single supplied with 0 and +9V.
Btw, best is to use a rail-to-rail op-amp when you deal with small voltages.


Try this

R4 is quite big to be sure the limited output swing of the opamp is enough to drive the voltage in NODE2 to both hysteresis limits.
If you simulate it, run the simulation at least 1 second to let the oscillation build up.
